# Twisted with repeated ERROR:twisted log on addErrback

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following twister code - version Twisted 13.1.0.

```
d=task.deferLater(reactor, 0, someFX1,arg1)
d.addCallback(someClient.send_FX2, ARG)
d.addErrback(fail)
```

With fail:

```
def fail(reason):
    log.err(reason)
    reactor.stop()
```

I had to add the addErrback so i could catch the errors from `someClient.send_FX2`

The problem is that, with the `d.addErrback(fail)`, the logs go crazy. There are know thousands of lines of ERROR:twisted - here is the tail of the logs.

```
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] ERROR:twisted:
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] 
2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [-] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1182, in mainLoop
        self.runUntilCurrent()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 805, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 381, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 489, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 576, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      (....)
    exceptions.AssertionError:  invalid XXX

2013-08-08 14:20:24+0100 [XXXXXXClientReceiver,client] Stopping factory <XXXXXXclient.XXXXXXClientFactory instance at 0x1c46a28>
```

Any idea on what is happening to create so many log entries?

Thanks.

**Update**

I had the python logging observer -

```
observer = log.PythonLoggingObserver()
observer.start()
```

Removing those, the logs went back to normal.

How can i set the observer without this logging problem?

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: Thanks. I'll post a new/different question.